# How to use regex in an RPM SPEC file?

Tags: regex, rpm, specifications

I'd like to list the files to be included in my package using a regular expression or the output of find.

How can I do that?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `'-f'` directive for `%files` to get list of files to be included from a file. That way you can generate the files to be included at the end of `%install` section

```
...
%install
...

find %{buildroot} -regex '.*a$' > file-lists

%files -f file-lists
...
```

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing right now, but I don't like messing with temporary files. Let's see if somebody comes up with a better solution

Comment: @GuillermoMA That is the ususal process, and it is no problem, as the files are cleaned up afterwards. I don't think there is a better one...